# php file query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a file /admin/php.php which has the following:

```
 <?php

 $ID=$_GET['ID'];

 require("../admin/config.php");

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contacttype IN ('New','Buyer','Seller','Buyer / Seller','Investor') AND leadstatus = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC";


$space = (!empty($row['firstname']) && !empty($row['lastname'])) ? ' ' : '';        
$name = $row['firstname'].$space.$row['lastname'];       
$partner  = $row['spousefirst'];   
$cell = (!empty($row['phonecell'])) ? " {$row['phonecell']} (cell)" : '';
$email = (!empty($row['email'])) ? " {$row['email']} (email)" : ''; 

mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

?>
```

On another page /admin/index.php I have:

```
<?php require("php.php"); ?>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/leads/view/?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?> "><strong><?php echo $name; ?></strong></a></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/leads/view/?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?> "><?php echo $partner; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['phonecell']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="mailto:<?php echo $row['email']; ?>"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo date("M jS, g:i A", strtotime($row['date'])); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['contacttype']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['agentassigned']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['leadstatus']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/contacts/notes.php?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">View </a>+ </td>
        <td><a href="/admin/contacts/todo.php?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">View </a>+ </td>
        <td><a href="/admin/contacts/deletesuccess.php?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">D</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>   
<?php
}
mysql_close(); 
?>
</table>
```

When I run this, I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /admin/index.php. I've tried removing the '}' after `<?php` in /admin/index.php and I get an error for unexpected $end in /admin/php.php. Really confused why this isn't working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you use any IDE that can show syntax errors?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a curly in "../admin/config.php" that is being left open?

Comment: @Fluffeh then he would get `unexpected $end` in config.php... not in php.php

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `}` should not be there. There is no opening `{` in this file, so there should not be a closing one.

Next up, `unexpected $end` - that error is in another file, so that's another problem.
The syntax of `php.php` *looks* valid, but:

1. your `mysql_query` call should return a result, and i don't see you assigning it to anything.
2. check that closing `?>` isn't followed/preceeded by non-printable characters we do not see here, but that can make parser choke - basically, remove that line, recreate it and save the file.

Comment: there was an opening there, just didn't have four spaces in front of it, my fault

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
}
mysql_close($sql); 
?>
```

You have closing bracket but I can't see opening.

Comment: there was one there, just didn't have four spaces, my fault.

Answer (score 0):

the "}" will cause an error from the code that is posted in your question. I'm not sure if this is all the code though.

also another question would be are you connection to a database at all? cause there is nothing in your code here that shows that either.

and you are not doing anything after the `mysql_query($sql)` is ran.